# Sign a MSOffice Document with SAPI

Tags: office-interop, cosign-api

I do know that in order to sign an MSOffice document, e.g. a Word document, one has to insert a signature line into document. Does anyone know how to do it programmatically using c# Office-Interop?

Using c# Office-Interop I can open,save convert to pdf but I could not find a way to insert signature line.

Comment: [AddSignatureLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.core.signatureset.addsignatureline%28v=office.15%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) opens the dialog. This [question from a MS Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4d48b60b-e7d1-48ad-b793-847d0bfa45a9/suppresshide-the-dialog-box-at-time-of-adding-digital-signature-to-a-word-document?forum=vsto) is similar.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Larry. I know now that it opens a dialogue and I can bypass it by using sendKey command. (Pretending to press Enter button). This is not  a problem. I would like to sign docx files without modifying its layout, without the signature line. When a document is signed with invisible signatures COSign API recognizes it and says that it is already signed. However I could not find a way to insert a non-signed invisible signature field.

Comment: This feature is by design, so one can hardly to add a signature line with delay signing. I am asking now If I purchase SDK, is the addon for MSOffice included?

Comment: Which SDK? Which addon? I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: the api in quesion is CoSign SAPI. I have installed a trial version and it came with an addon. I have a new ribbon in MSWord which signs documents with CoSign.

Comment: Ok. The MS Word addon source is not available. That Word addon is no longer needed for signing MS Word docs since Word now includes digital signature support. The Word SignatureLine should generally be used instead of the addon. You can re-distribute the addon to your signers if you need to.